# How to create a .pdf file in ios?

Tags: ios

I have an image or any text. I want to create a PDF file like `test.pdf`.
And after creating pdf file i want to mail that file with `MailComposer`.
Please anybody can suggest how can i create the `.pdf` file in ios coding ?

Comment: Did you do any searching? Did you at least look at the list of related question?

Comment: Please, you can edit my questions, i am new in ios and stackoverflow also. please don't give negative voting to my questions, if possible you can edit my questions

Comment: If you wish to avoid getting down voted, please click the help link above and read about how to ask a proper question. Your question is far too broad and shows no effort on your part to do any research. This is not a "I'm too lazy to do any work, please give me the code" website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pdf create button click action write this code..

```
 #import "PDF_Screen.h"

// Create Pdf...

PDF_Screen *loPdf = [[PDF_Screen alloc] init]; // this is class for create pdf file
[loPdf createPDF:@"Report.Pdf"];

// Attach with mail ......

Mail_Screen *lomailscreen = [[Mail_Screen alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
lomailscreen.mToRecepient = @"";
lomailscreen.mSubject = @"Budget Report";
lomailscreen.mBody = @"";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:lomailscreen animated:YES];
```

Here i am going to write code for pdf class..

**PDF_Screen.h**

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface PDF_Screen : NSObject

 {

 }

 void CreatePDFFile (CGRect pageRect, const char *filename);
 - (void)createPDF:(NSString *)PdfFilename;
 @end
```

**PDF_Screen.m**

```
 #import "PDF_Screen.h"

 @implementation PDF_Screen

 -(id)init
 {
self = [super init];
if (self) 
{

}
return self ;
 }

 -(void)createPDF:(NSString *)PdfFilename
 {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *saveDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *saveFileName = PdfFilename ;
NSString *newFilePath = [saveDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];
const char *filename = [newFilePath UTF8String];

    CreatePDFFile(CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 345), filename);

 }

void CreatePDFFile (CGRect pageRect , const char *filename)
{
CGContextRef pdfContext;
CFStringRef path;
CFURLRef url;
CFMutableDictionaryRef myDictionary = NULL;

// Create a CFString from the filename we provide to this method when we call it
path = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, filename,kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

// Create a CFURL using the CFString we just defined
url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path,kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);

CFRelease (path);

// This dictionary contains extra options mostly for 'signing' the PDF
myDictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0,&kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,&kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextTitle, CFSTR("My PDF File"));
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextCreator, CFSTR("My Name"));

// Create our PDF Context with the CFURL, the CGRect we provide, and the above defined dictionary
pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL (url, &pageRect, myDictionary);

// Cleanup our mess
CFRelease(myDictionary);
CFRelease(url);

// Done creating our PDF Context, now it's time to draw to it

// Starts our first page
CGContextBeginPage (pdfContext, &pageRect);

// Draws a black rectangle around the page inset by 20 on all sides
CGContextStrokeRect(pdfContext, CGRectMake(20, 20, pageRect.size.width - 40, pageRect.size.height - 40));

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *saveDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *saveFileName = @"Picture.jpeg" ;
NSString *newFilePath = [saveDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];

UIImage *newUIImage1 =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:newFilePath]; 

NSData * data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newUIImage1, 0.95);
UIImage * compressedImage1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data1];
CGImageRef image1 = [compressedImage1 CGImage];

CGContextDrawImage (pdfContext, CGRectMake(21, 21, 278, 303),image1);

// We are done drawing to this page, let's end it
// We could add as many pages as we wanted using CGContextBeginPage/CGContextEndPage
CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);

// We are done with our context now, so we release it
CGContextRelease (pdfContext);

}

-(void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I think this'll help you..:)

Comment: Thanks for accept my answer. i'll give you a link . if you need any more information please follow this link.   http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1